# Unity share dialog error: com.facebook.FacebookException: Failed to get app name

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine

I'm using Facebook SDK v 6.2.2 for Unity, Unity 5.2.

I'm trying to use `FB.Share` function to share something to user's wall. It used to run, but now it cannot run and outputs the following error:

> V/FBUnitySDK: sending to Unity OnFeedRequestComplete({"error":"com.facebook.FacebookException: Failed to get app name.","callback_id":"2"})

My game is in Public Mode (not Sandbox Mode). My account has the `developer` role. I've tested on mobile and Unity editor, and both have the same error.

Answer (score 0):

For Unity 5 onwards, please use the Unity SDK 7.x. Lower version won't work correctly.